# Mathematical physics applications in present-day image processing

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition

During the past few years several important areas of image processing and image classification or generation became dominated by convolutional neural networks.

I'm interested if there are any methods coming from mathematical physics context (like methods designed for solving ill-posed problems, spectral analysis, image deblurring and deringing), that outperform neural network-based approaches in 2017 for some common computer vision or image processing problem. Or methods that don't have any neural network-based rivals. Maybe in the field of biomedical image analysis (just a guess)?

The deeper and more specific the answer is, the better.

Comment: I imagine that to beat deep learning methods you would have to be operating in the small data or simple model regime because neural networks shine when data is abundant and computational resources are not constrained. If you're looking for a research topic, I think the [scattering transform](http://www.di.ens.fr/data/scattering/image/) is interesting and neglected.

Comment: @Emre Yes, I look for a research topic that would actually be useful in practical applications. Thanks for the link, looks interesting.